# Unbounce Stylesheets not working

Tags: css, unbounce

I'm working on an Unbounce project and I can't get the stylesheets to work.

I wanted to change the font-size of the labels of an option on the form. I saw (using inspect element) that the following CSS created affects the size: `#lp-pom-form-55 .lp-pom-form-field .option label`

So I created a stylesheet in Unbounce like this:

```
<style>
  #lp-pom-form-55 .lp-pom-form-field .option label {
      font-size: 16px !important;
  }
</style>
```

And it just doesn't work.  I also tried it without the style tag like this:

```
#lp-pom-form-55 .lp-pom-form-field .option label {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

It still didn't work. I even tried basic things like setting the background color of normal text field id's to `black !important` with no solution.

What is the correct way to apply styles to Unbounce pages?

Comment: I'm using Unbounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that the code within the `<style>` tags is the correct way to do it. The problem was that the custom CSS doesn't display in the designer view, it only shows on the live page.